# Why SQL mode is removed for ViewObject in JDEV latest version

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, bc4j

In ViewObject creation wizard (Entity Object), the sql mode(Expert mode, Declarative mode ) is not available in JDEV latest version? Is it intentional ? Or it is possible to add  tag declaratively in the ViewObject?

Comment: What is the latest version according to you?

Answer (score 1):

For JDeveloper 12.1.3.0 (and possibly, future releases) you can still add custom queries.

Please read 5.8.1 and 5.8.3 (How to Create a Custom SQL Mode View Object) of the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-bc-vo-queries.htm#ADFFD307

In short (5.8.1):

> In the Applications window, right-click the package in which you want
>   to create the view object and choose New and then View Object.
>
> If you have not yet created a database connection for the data model
>   project, in the Initialize Business Components Project dialog, select
>   the database connection or choose New to create a connection. Click
>   OK.
>
> If this is the first component you're creating in the project, the
>   Initialize Business Components Project dialog appears to allow you to
>   select a database connection.
>
> In the Create View Object wizard, on the Name page, enter a package
>   name and a view object name. Select Custom SQL query to indicate that
>   you want this view object to manage data without the benefit of entity
>   objects. Click Next. --- Fill in you custom query --- ect.

In short (5.8.3):

> To enable custom SQL mode, select Write Custom SQL on the Query page
>   of the Create View Object wizard. You can also modify the SQL
>   statement of an existing **entity-based view object** in the view object
>   overview editor. In the overview editor, navigate to the Query page
>   and select Write Custom SQL.